# Show set is subset of other set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

For every $ u \in \mathbb Q $, let $L_u=\{s \in \mathbb Q  \mid s < u \} $
Gather these sets in a new set $S=\{L_u \mid u \in \mathbb Q \} \subseteq 2^ \mathbb Q$

Let $ u,v \in \mathbb Q $ Show $ L_u \subseteq L_v $ if, and only if $ u \le v $

I need some hints and help on where to start with this problem.

Comment: Just show that $x\in L_u$ implies that $x\in L_V$?

Comment: But what about the if and only if $ u \le v$ ?

Comment: Yes, that was implicit. Formally you could state: Let $u,v\in\mathbb{Q}$  such that $u\leq v$. Then $x\in L_u$ implies $x\in L_v$.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need for the new set $S$.
What you need are:
1. Suppose $L_u\subseteq L_v$, then show $u\le v$. I would try proof by contradiction.
2. Suppose $u\le v$, then show $L_u\subseteq L_v$. That is, show that if $s\in L_u$, then $s\in L_v$.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose $u>v$; then
$$
v<\frac{u+v}{2}<u
$$
so …

Suppose $u\le v$ and let $s\in L_u$; can you prove that $s\in L_v$?